# Selenium Pagination

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, pagination, object-oriented-analysis

I am trying to get all links with pagination. I am using selenium. Since there is more than ten thousand data, it will take time to get all links and some informations in it. I want to use pagination. After taking ten linkS, it should click next button. and take other ten links. If you have any suggestion instead of using selenium, I am happy to hear that. Here is my code, how can integrate pagination into my code? Thanks for your help

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd

import undetected_chromedriver as uc


import time




website='https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=&term=&cntry=TR&state=&city=&dist='
path=r"C:\Users\kaant\Downloads\chromedriver.exe"
service=Service(executable_path=path)
#driver=uc.Chrome(service=service)
#driver.get(website)


options = uc.ChromeOptions() 
options.headless = True 
driver = uc.Chrome() 
driver.get(website) 
driver.maximize_window() 
time.sleep(2) 


b=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, value=".//td/a")

country_links = [element.get_attribute("href") for element in
                driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, value=".//td/a")]
    
cc=country_links[1:-1:2]
cc.append(country_links[-1])
```

then it should go to next page and do the same

Answer (score 1):

You can use their Ajax API to download the data, for example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

payload = {
    "draw": "4",
    "columns[0][data]": "0",
    "columns[0][name]": "",
    "columns[0][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[0][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[0][search][value]": "",
    "columns[0][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[1][data]": "1",
    "columns[1][name]": "",
    "columns[1][searchable]": "false",
    "columns[1][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[1][search][value]": "",
    "columns[1][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[2][data]": "2",
    "columns[2][name]": "",
    "columns[2][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[2][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[2][search][value]": "",
    "columns[2][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[3][data]": "3",
    "columns[3][name]": "",
    "columns[3][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[3][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[3][search][value]": "",
    "columns[3][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[4][data]": "4",
    "columns[4][name]": "",
    "columns[4][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[4][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[4][search][value]": "",
    "columns[4][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[5][data]": "5",
    "columns[5][name]": "",
    "columns[5][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[5][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[5][search][value]": "",
    "columns[5][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[6][data]": "6",
    "columns[6][name]": "",
    "columns[6][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[6][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[6][search][value]": "",
    "columns[6][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[7][data]": "7",
    "columns[7][name]": "",
    "columns[7][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[7][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[7][search][value]": "",
    "columns[7][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[8][data]": "8",
    "columns[8][name]": "",
    "columns[8][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[8][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[8][search][value]": "",
    "columns[8][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[9][data]": "9",
    "columns[9][name]": "",
    "columns[9][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[9][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[9][search][value]": "",
    "columns[9][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[10][data]": "10",
    "columns[10][name]": "",
    "columns[10][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[10][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[10][search][value]": "",
    "columns[10][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[11][data]": "11",
    "columns[11][name]": "",
    "columns[11][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[11][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[11][search][value]": "",
    "columns[11][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[12][data]": "12",
    "columns[12][name]": "",
    "columns[12][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[12][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[12][search][value]": "",
    "columns[12][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[13][data]": "13",
    "columns[13][name]": "",
    "columns[13][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[13][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[13][search][value]": "",
    "columns[13][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[14][data]": "14",
    "columns[14][name]": "",
    "columns[14][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[14][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[14][search][value]": "",
    "columns[14][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[15][data]": "15",
    "columns[15][name]": "",
    "columns[15][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[15][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[15][search][value]": "",
    "columns[15][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[16][data]": "16",
    "columns[16][name]": "",
    "columns[16][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[16][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[16][search][value]": "",
    "columns[16][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[17][data]": "17",
    "columns[17][name]": "",
    "columns[17][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[17][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[17][search][value]": "",
    "columns[17][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[18][data]": "18",
    "columns[18][name]": "",
    "columns[18][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[18][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[18][search][value]": "",
    "columns[18][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[19][data]": "19",
    "columns[19][name]": "",
    "columns[19][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[19][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[19][search][value]": "",
    "columns[19][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[20][data]": "20",
    "columns[20][name]": "",
    "columns[20][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[20][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[20][search][value]": "",
    "columns[20][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[21][data]": "21",
    "columns[21][name]": "",
    "columns[21][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[21][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[21][search][value]": "",
    "columns[21][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[22][data]": "22",
    "columns[22][name]": "",
    "columns[22][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[22][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[22][search][value]": "",
    "columns[22][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[23][data]": "23",
    "columns[23][name]": "",
    "columns[23][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[23][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[23][search][value]": "",
    "columns[23][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[24][data]": "24",
    "columns[24][name]": "",
    "columns[24][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[24][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[24][search][value]": "",
    "columns[24][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[25][data]": "25",
    "columns[25][name]": "",
    "columns[25][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[25][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[25][search][value]": "",
    "columns[25][search][regex]": "false",
    "start": 0,
    "length": 100,
    "search[value]": "",
    "search[regex]": "false",
}


api_url = 'https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results/rpc/Xi0yqBcxWwU59HGn'

for payload['start'] in range(0, 300, 100):  # <--- increase number of pages here
    data = requests.post(api_url, data=payload).json()
    # print only data from column 3:
    for row in data['data']:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(row[3], 'html.parser')
        print('{:<80} {}'.format(soup.a.text[:80], 'https://clinicaltrials.gov' + soup.a['href']))
```

Prints:

```
Two Different Dietary Interventions for Girls With Polycystic Ovary Syndrome     https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT05768724?cntry=TR&draw=4&rank=1
Laparoscopic Extraperitoneal ( Modified) Burch Colposuspension                   https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT05768607?cntry=TR&draw=4&rank=2
Whole Body Vibration Training Applied With Different Frequencies in Hypertensive https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT05768555?cntry=TR&draw=4&rank=3
Assignment of the Verbal Component Score and Addition of Pupil Reaction to the G https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT05767502?cntry=TR&draw=4&rank=4
Comparison of 3 Different Protocols for Preventing Premature Ovulation in Ovaria https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT05767086?cntry=TR&draw=4&rank=5
Web-Based Intercultural Midwifery Training Given to Midwifery Students           https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT05766228?cntry=TR&draw=4&rank=6
The Effect of Motor Imagery and Action Observation on Motor Skill Acquisition    https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT05765708?cntry=TR&draw=4&rank=7
Effects of Dual-Task Training In Individuals With Alzheimer                      https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT05765552?cntry=TR&draw=4&rank=8
The Effects of Topical Hyaluronic Acid and Laser Application on Wound Healing in https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT05765240?cntry=TR&draw=4&rank=9
Investigation of the Efficiency of Spinal Mobilization in Patients With Adolesce https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT05765019?cntry=TR&draw=4&rank=10
Endorphin Massage Application to Women Who Gave Birth Vaginally                  https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT05764512?cntry=TR&draw=4&rank=11

...and so on.
```